Protecting circuit from high voltage arc
I have a circuit measuring leakage current (typically between 100pA - 1mA at DC to 10Hz) of materials at voltages up to 10kV.  The test is layed out basically as shown below.  The problem is the material sometimes breaks down, with a spark jumping the gap where the material was (usually through the material). The high voltage supply will trip (manufacturer doesn't provide a time), but there is the output capacitance + the coax cable capacitance (maybe a few 100 pF) that are charged.
Despite my efforts to protect the opamp trying different TVS diodes, and trying a range of different opamps, it still sometimes gets fried after the breakdown event and needs replacing.  I'm curious to know if there is any other way that the opamp in the TIA can be protected?


Put a resistor in series with the high voltage supply.

@Hearth That might work, but for the extreme dynamic range of the leakage current measurement -- which spans 7 orders of magnitude.

Try a sparkgap.
